# FullCalendar: Events not showing onload but show if I open IE developer

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar jquery pluging in my MVC3 project.

For some reason events aren't rendered when the calendar is first loaded. The strange thing is that  they do appear if I open IE developer or if I change the agenda view.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Is your calendar div in a hidden element on load - like inside a tab or a dialog?

Comment: yes, the calendar control is in a jquery tab.

Comment: Cool! I added an answer explaining what you can do for calendars in hidden tabs. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your calendar div is in a hidden element like a tab. You will need to render the fullCalendar on show of this hidden element to load your events properly in the calendar.

In case of jQuery tabs, you can do something like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    show: function(event, ui) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps!